# Lost Residence Permit, but have confirmation of new permit and photocopy, advice required

Tags: air-travel, indian-citizens, hungary, lost-documents, entry-permit

I require some advice regarding the entry into Hungary. I am Indian national who has been living in Hungary for past 2 years with a long term(student) residence permit. Recently, I lost my permit at Budapest to some pickpocket. I notified it to the permit issuing immigration authority at Budapest and at the police. I have also received the confirmation of a new residence permit for me from the issuing authority. I also have a copy of the lost residence permit.

Together I have- My original passport, the copy of the lost permit, the new confirmation of granting me a new replacement residence permit along with the number of the permit in it and other ID docs.

Now, I have traveled back to India back to home for my holidays without any hassle from Budapest Airport Authorities and I will be again returning back to Budapest by September and will take the replacement card there.

Now the concern is, will I able to make the re-entry with the documents mentioned like I did when I left Hungary.

(I already have booked my flight and I had no problems with the airport immigration officials when I left Hungary.)

Please help me with my query as soon as possible if it's relevant.

Comment: Ask it to https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/  This is not a travel question.

Comment: why don't you ask Immigration at Budapest airport directly. Their email address is rri@rri.police.hu

Comment: I asked them though email last week, there isn't a reply yet.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi You don't think the question of what documentation is needed to travel to a country is a travel question?

Answer (score 2):

Before you can deal with immigration at Budapest airport, you will have to deal with the airline.

I doubt they'll let you board because the confirmation you have is not listed on internationally published list of documents granting you entry to Hungary; and it is airlines' legal duty to play by that list. Moreover, if that confirmation is in Hungarian, airline staff in your country won't even be able to establish what sort of document that is.

You should have got a temporary 'bridging' visa before you left Hungary. This is essentially a D category visa, and such visas are issued by EU member countries in situations like yours. You should still be able to apply for such a visa in your local consular post of Hungary before return. A decision to grant you a residence permit was already made, so issuance of the visa must be a formal process.

Comment: I checked with some airlines around me, they told it was ok if I provided the confirmation